# Exclude path pattern from Camel REST

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator, spring-camel

The following task has been set.  There is a project on the Spring-Camel(+Actuator) stack.  The following parameters are set in the properties:

1. server.servlet.context_path=/application_name
2. camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/api/*
3. management.endpoints.web.base-path=monitor

These settings provide the following functionality:

Camel REST endpoints contain the following path: http://localhost:8080/application_name/api/endpoint_name

The metrics are on the path: http://localhost:8080/application_name/monitor/*

It is necessary to remove the word api from the path for endpoints, however, if you set the property to the following value camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*, monitor stops working and camel treats it as an endpoint (gives 404).  Who can tell if there is a solution for this problem?  Cannot change the monitor path.

I thought about the possibility of excluding a certain path pattern from Camel, but did not find this setting).